# Mysql import from excel table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, import, phpexcel

I have excel table with several thousands of rows. Amount of columns changes through time. I use this code to create columns in MySQL:

```
$headings = $sheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $highestColumn . 1,
NULL,
TRUE,
FALSE);
$i=1;
$c=1;
$name = 'name';
foreach($headings[0] as $x => $x_value) {
$date = date('d-m-y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($c, $i)->getValue()));
$sql = "ALTER TABLE stats ADD `$date` INT(3) AFTER `$name`";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
var_dump($sql);
$c++;
$name = $date;
}
```

After I have to insert data into each column I have created before. This is how I get data from xlsx:

```
while ($row <= $highestRow):
 $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        FALSE);
foreach($rowData[0] as $x => $x_value) {
echo $x_value, '<br>';
}
endwhile;
```

I don't get how to form MySql query to import all rows in database.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, is it a true [Excel Table object](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) or just a tabular region of columns and rows on worksheet? Second, are you adding data to just new columns or old and new ones? Constantly recreating a table is not best practices as databases should be stable objects, otherwise use a spreadsheet or other flat files. Curious why not use VBA to have Excel directly connect to MySQL without PHP?

Comment: 1) I guess it is tabular region of columns and rows.   2) New and old 3)Sure, recreating table is not the best practice. I will rewrite this part. Php will check if column exists and add one only if not.  4) Users will add new xls in browser so it has to be simple.

Comment: Because 1 VBA stinks, 2 granting remote access to DML is bad enough and in this case he would have to also grant DDL which is a nightmare. Making the import through php, in this case, is the better practice.

Comment: @megagosha good, I was going to write that. You could also keep the rows you don't query in a generic json column. Can you let us know more about why you need to do this?

Comment: This table is employees monthly results. It will be used to calculate their salary. Plus it will be used in their work analysis to calculate reject rate (there is one more table) and determine toxic employees.